# Searching within JSON with PHP for server side implementation of autocomplete jQuery plugin

Tags: php, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to use jQuery Autocomplete Plugin in my PHP web application.
I have a JSON file on the server that has the data for the search. It looks like this:

```
{
    "_E161": {
        "keggId":"rn:R05223",
        "abbrev":"ADOCBLS",
        "name":"Adenosylcobalamin 5'-phosphate synthase",
        "equation":"agdpcbi[c] + rdmbzi[c]  -> h[c] + adocbl[c] + gmp[c] ",
    },
    "_E163": {
         ....
    }
}
```

I would like to go through this JSON file (has 3500 entries) with PHP script that gets search term from the jQuery autocomplete plugin. Then return the entries that contain search term back to client side to populate autocomplete.
What would be a better way to implement this? My first guess is to loop through the JSON file and use [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) But I suspect that might be slow?

Comment: I would look at how many kb that entire file ends up being after you strip whitespace and gzip it. There's a decent chance it ends up small enough to just serve the entire file and just do pure lightning fast autocomplete totally clientside.

Comment: @chris that is exactly what i'm trying to do for right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use on preg_grep (Return array entries that match the pattern),

```
// sanitize, and perform some processing to ensure is a valid regex pattern
$pattern = ...;

$json = json_decode( ... );
$arr  = array();
foreach ($json as $key=>$arr)
{
  $arr[$key] = $arr['name'];
}
$matches = preg_grep("/$pattern/i", $arr);
// $matches will hold the matches
// and you refer back to the $json using associate key
```